# Change landing page of web app from login page to some other page

Tags: java, html, authentication, web-applications

I have developed a webapp. Earlier it was in-built login authentication page which is now is replaced with 3rd Party Authentication page. Once the user logins through 3rd Party authentication, the user will be redirected to my app. Now what changes i have to make in my code in order to do this? 
I already know about making changes in web.xml file but its not working.

Comment: Can we see some code here?

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma - java code or xhtml file ??

Comment: provide some more info about your application. Any framework? MVC, Struts, .. JSF?

Comment: The 3rd Party will redirect to a specifics URL of your application. Your problem is to get the authenticated user information or to redirect him to a landing page?

Comment: @FrancescoPirrone - My problem is actually both. I need the authenticated user information so that i can get their roles and on the basis of roles, they can access the Wab app. And then the user can be redirected to a landing page.